# About the definition of Day's convolution

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I'm struggling with the definition of Day's convolution.

Given a monoidal category $(\mathcal C,\otimes, I)$, there is a way to define a monoidal product on the category of presheaves $\widehat{\mathcal C}$. This monoidal product, called the Day's convolution, has nice properties (e.g. it makes $\widehat{\mathcal C}$ a closed monoidal category). The definition of Day's convolution given in [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution) (and any other source I can get) is the following: for all presheaves $F,G$ on $\mathcal C$,
$$ F\otimes G := \int^{c,d \in \mathcal C} F(c)\times G(d) \times \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,c\otimes d). $$

My problem is that I can't infer from the (abusive notation of the) coend what is the source category of the diagram. Usually, a coend is the universal dinatural cocone over a diagram $\Delta \colon \mathcal E^{\rm op}\times\mathcal E \to \mathcal F$. Here, obviously $\mathcal F$ should be $\widehat{\mathcal C}$. Bu what should be $\mathcal E$?

I'm tempted to take $\mathcal C \times \mathcal C$ because $(c,d)\mapsto F(c)\times G(d)$ and $(c,d) \mapsto \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,c\otimes d)$ have opposite variances, but then, taking the coend of the pointwise product of those functors, I should get
$$ \int^{c,d,c',d'\in\mathcal C} F(c)\times G(d)\times \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,c'\otimes d'). $$

What am I missing here?

**Edit.** $\mathcal E$ should be $\mathcal C$. My misunderstanding came from notations. Following the notation of a colimit of a diagram $D \colon \mathcal E \to \mathcal F$ as $ \operatorname{colim}_{e \in \mathcal E} D(e)$, I thought that the exponent of the integral was designating the source category of the diagram, when actually the coend of $D \colon {\mathcal E}^{\rm op} \times \mathcal E \to \mathcal F$ is denoted $\int^{e \in \mathcal E} D(e,e)$.

(A special thanks to Mariano Suárez-Alvarez who has been really patient with me.)

Comment: Clearly, $\mathcal E$ should be $\mathcal C$: that is precisely what the upper index in the integral sign means!

Comment: coend is the 'integration' over the diagonal, so you need $c=c', d=d'$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez If $\mathcal E$ is $\mathcal C$ then the diagram should be covariant in the variable $d$. But $G$ is a presheaf...

Comment: No: you have a functor $((c,d),(c',d'))\to F(c)\times G(d)\times\hom(-,c'\otimes d')$ defined on $(E\times E)\times(E\times E)$, and taking the diagonal there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez We have $F\colon\mathcal C^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ and $G\colon\mathcal C^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$, which gives a functor $H \colon \mathcal C^{\rm op} \times \mathcal C^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ defined as $(c,d) \to F(c)\times G(d)$. Composing with the functor that sends a set to the constant presheaf of values this set, this gives $\tilde H \colon \mathcal C^{\rm op} \times \mathcal C^{\rm op} \to \widehat{\mathcal C}$. On the other hand we have $\mathfrak h \colon \mathcal C\times \mathcal C\to \widehat{\mathcal C}$ given by $(c,d) \to \hom(-,c\otimes d)$ [...]

Comment: [...] so I end up with a functor $(\mathcal C\times \mathcal C)^{\rm op} \times (\mathcal C\times \mathcal C) \to \widehat{\mathcal C}$ given by $(c,d,c',d') \mapsto F(c)\times G(d) \times \hom(-,c'\otimes d')$. Now, what diagonal are you taking?

Comment: The only one that gives the formula you want, and the one that Ma Ming mentioned!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez So we want to take a **functor** $\mathcal C^{\rm op} \times \mathcal C \to (\mathcal C \times \mathcal C)^{\rm op} \times (\mathcal C \times \mathcal C)$ defined by $(c,d) \mapsto (c,d,c,d)$ and precompose with it. That means we want two functor $\mathcal C^{\rm op} \times \mathcal C \to (\mathcal C \times \mathcal C)^{\rm op}$ and $\mathcal C^{\rm op} \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C \times \mathcal C$ both being the identity on objects: that what is bothering me, I don't see how it is possible!

Comment: Well, this is how coends work... You do not really do that composition of functors: that's just notation/

Comment: @Pece: How much are you familiar with coend calculus? Why do you think you want those functors to be identity on objects? Writing $\int^{c,d,c',d'\in\mathcal C} F(c)\times G(d)\times \hom_{\mathcal C}(-,c'\otimes d')$ simply doesn't make sense, according to the def of coend :)

Comment: @tetrapharmakon Ok, I think I just got it: the coend of a functor $D \colon \mathcal E^{op} \times \mathcal E \to \mathcal F$ is denoted $\int^{e \in \mathcal E} D(e,e)$ and not $\int^{e,e'\in\mathcal E} D(e,e')$? Is that it? If so, my struggling was just about a (very counterintuitive I must say) notation.

Comment: It is exactly as intuitive as notation for ordinary integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\E{\mathbf E}\def\D{\mathbf D}$It's not counterintuitive at all when you understand how coends work!

It takes a while but once you understand it, you understand it forever. According to the definition of coend as a universal cowedge, writing $\int^{e, e'}F(e,e')$ means that you are considering a functor $F\colon \E\times \E^{op}\times \E\times \E^{op} \to \D$ which is mute in the third and fourth $\E$-component; taking its coend, then, would give you $\varinjlim_{e,e'}F$, which is generally different from $\int^e F$ (see Exercise 1.17 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v2.pdf)).

In the end (!), you're right that it is something similar to a matter of taste in choosing the notation. But several notations are to be preferred to others because they grasp the "right" meaning of the structure we want to describe.

Now, there are several *practical* reasons why one should prefer denoting a coend as something like $\int^c F(c,c)$. Are you familiar with the Einstein convention in tensor calculus? Whenever ou are summing over repeated indices the sum symbol can be suppressed. Something similar (explain to yourself why! Or read Def 5.3 [ibi](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v2.pdf).) happens with co/ends.

Now for your question: once you understand the basic machinery behind coends, you can effortlessly prove something more general, working out the exercises in Appendix A [ibi](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the paper: it seems not only interesting but also fun to read.

Comment: That's precisely the spirit of that paper :) (btw, I'm the author)